# ASP.net Global.asax error detail in Application_Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to get detailed Error in Application_Error of Global.asax.

I use `Server.GetLastError().Message`, but it returns `Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.`

I need more detail, how can I do that? in asp.net C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I was looking for `Server.GetLastError().InnerException`. It returns fully detailed Error message.

Answer (score 3):

Are you searching for Server.GetLastError().StackTrace ? If not, please explain what do you want to be shown?